# I can't open git bash

Tags: git

I'm trying to upload a project on Github. I've already created a repository and I have git installed but when I go to the project folder and try to open git bash instead of opening it creates a new file called `mintty.exe.stampduck` which when I open in notepad I see this

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=0006031C eax=00000000 ebx=0045028B ecx=ED3987A0 edx=77EECB90 esi=004A0410 edi=80000000 ebp=0023CB38 esp=0023C61C 
program=C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\mintty.exe, pid 1121, thread main cs=001B ds=0023 es=0023 fs=003B gs=0000 ss=0023 
Stack trace: Frame Function Args 0023CB38 0006031C (20060F90, 20060F9A, 0023CD18, 6100AFA5) 0023CD18 6100AFA5 (00000000, 0023CD74, 61009DD0, 00000000) 0023CD74 610088B2 (00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000) 
End of stack trace
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Git for Windows installed? Do you have any third-party security software running on your PC?

Comment: I do have the latest version.I don't  know what a third-party security software is. I'm not good at this computer stuff.

Comment: "Third-party" means it's from someone other than you or Microsoft, who are the two primary parties involved in the business transaction that is having Windows installed on your PC. Security software includes, but is not limited to, things like anti-virus and firewall (which are two of the most likely culprits).

Comment: Consider rewording your question. The title and beginning claim you're having trouble uploading to GitHub, but the end says you're unable to open Git Bash. While you need to solve the problem in order to push to GitHub, the problem is not related to that function.   Have you tried reinstalling git?